# Copying each object in a plot separately as an image

Tags: plotting, graphics, image, office

I would like to copy a plot from *Mathematica* as an image, into a PowerPoint slide. This plot has two curves. When I try to do the (naïve) usual "copy graphics" and paste, I find the full plot (along with the two curves) as a single image.

I wish to copy the image such that powerpoint can view the plot as three different objects:

1. The X-Y axes alone.
2. Curve 1
3. Curve 2

Here is an example of two functions and the plot:

```
f[x_] := (1 - x)^20 + 12*(1 - x)^19*x + 225*(1 - x)^18*x^2 +
         1820*(1 - x)^17*x^3 + 13182*(1 - x)^16*x^4 + 16112*(1 - x)^15*x^5 +
         15681*(1 - x)^14*x^6 + 15395*(1 - x)^13*x^7 + 15226*(1 - x)^12*x^8 +
         15141*(1 - x)^11*x^9 + 15127*(1 - x)^10*x^10 + 15152*(1 - x)^9*x^11 +
         15210*(1 - x)^8*x^12 + 15266*(1 - x)^7*x^13 + 15339*(1 - x)^6*x^14 +
         15403*(1 - x)^5*x^15 + 15465*(1 - x)^4*x^16 + 15517*(1 - x)^3*x^17 +
         15564*(1 - x)^2*x^18 + 15622*(1 - x)*x^19 + 15684*x^20;

g[x_] := (641135*(1 - x)^15*x^5)/171 + (802276*(1 - x)^14*x^6)/95 +
         (15581573*(1 - x)^13*x^7)/855 + (15099914*(1 - x)^12*x^8)/855 +
         (172649*(1 - x)^11*x^9)/10 + (14529139*(1 - x)^10*x^10)/855 +
         (5748121*(1 - x)^9*x^11)/342 + (950524*(1 - x)^8*x^12)/57 +
         (14169122*(1 - x)^7*x^13)/855 + (939301*(1 - x)^6*x^14)/57 +
         (1556712*(1 - x)^5*x^15)/95 + (27851407*(1 - x)^4*x^16)/1710 +
         (27665347*(1 - x)^3*x^17)/1710 + (305276*(1 - x)^2*x^18)/19 +
         (606145*(1 - x)*x^19)/38 + (2306804*x^20)/285;

Plot[ {0.1 f[p], g[p]},
      {p, 0, 1/2},
      PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}},
      LabelStyle -> Large,
      AxesStyle -> Thick ]
```

Can I make *Mathematica* output three objects separately ? In that case I can copy each one and paste them in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
f[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] := Plot[{0.1 f[p], g[p]}, {p, 0, 1/2}, 
                      PlotStyle -> {{Thick, p1}, {Thick, p2}}, 
                      AxesStyle -> p3, 
                      LabelStyle -> Large, AxesStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 200]
t = Transparent;
Row[f /@ {{t, t, Automatic}, {Red, t, t}, {t, Blue, t}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then copy each plot to PowerPoint as (for example) enhanced metagraphics.

Select each plot in PP and use "Picture Tools", "Format", "Recolor", "Set Transparent Color" and select the white background:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can combine all three plots as one again:

[image: Mathematica graphics]